# ember cli freezes on IE11 says not responding due to long running script

Tags: ember.js, internet-explorer-11, ember-cli

The home page loads, but then when I log in the app freezes. It works on `IE10`.I ran a profile with F12 and I can't seem to narrow down why it's taking so long. Can anyone please help me debug this?

[image]